# The method 'fromARGB' isn't defined for the type 'Color' error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to upgrade my flutter project to null safety, but I got an error from following code:

```
  new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String?>(
        id: 'Goal',
        seriesCategory: 'A',
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: zielData,
        colorFn: (_, __) =>
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color.fromARGB(226, 6, 68, 1)),
      )
```

the error:

```
The method 'fromARGB' isn't defined for the type 'Color'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromARGB'
```

Dose anyone knows why? And how to fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try running `flutter clean` and maybe restart your IDE or even reboot your PC

Comment: + make sure to import material

Comment: `fromDartColor` is just a convenience function that calls the (r, g, b, a) constructor of `charts_flutter`'s own `Color` class. Skip the Flutter color middleman. (Note that you have at least two `Color` classes around: Flutter's one and charts_flutter's one. Make sure you are clear which is which - drill into them with, for example ^B in Android studio, to confirm you have the correct imports.

Comment: @RichardHeap you are right. I imported ```import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';``` because of ```seriesList as List<Series<dynamic, String>>,```. And this package causes the error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
but now it's solved.
What mistake i did was that i created one data.dart file. and in this file i created class to store all colors and this class' name was class color{}.
**now flutter was confused between predefined color class and my new defined color class**

**> Check that if you had custom made class named Color if you made new class named color than change name of that class**

TO check this if using vs code press ctrl and click color.fromARGB it will lead you to actual location for color class if it you custom than rename it